# easi package on R studio 4.0

Tags: r, r-package

the easi package (exact affine stone index model) is a bit old, but still  useful for my purposes. Has anybody managed to install it on Rstudio 4 considering it was built on R 2.15.3?
Thanks

Comment: You can install it from source provided you install the additional dependency/dependencies. I downloaded it from https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2014-08-18_0233/web/packages/easi/index.html and installed it using `install.packages("micEcon"); install.packages("easi_0.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source"); library(easi)`. I just tried to run the example from the vignette and I'm running into an error though, which is not ideal (`Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL`). I'll have a look at the source code and try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @jared_mamrot  Thanks a lot. I found the code on github, would that help?  See link herehttps://github.com/khaeru/easi

Comment: Under the extreme circumstance, could I just copy and paste portions of the code on R and proceed? or build the package using the code?

Comment: I spent some time updating/fixing the source code @MarioF and it's working again. I'll post the solution as an answer. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: has anybody found a way to model the censored version of the EASI? that is, estimating the probit prior the specification of the easi.

Comment: Hi @MarioF, this isn't my area of expertise, but I'm happy to take a look. Is there a specific function related to 'estimating the probit prior the specification of the easi' that isn't working? Or is your question about finding probit modelling functions and has nothing to do with the EASI package? E.g. [censReg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censReg/vignettes/censReg.pdf) or something similar?

Comment: HI @jared_mamrot , please see here the thread on this matter and a link to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the github repository and updated the source code to fix the `Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL` error @MarioF. The example from the vignette now runs to completion. I'm not certain that the answers are correct, as I don't have anything to compare them to, but based on the source code it looks fine to me. If you've run easi in the past, perhaps you could re-run it using this updated version and see if the results are the same.

You can install the updated easi package using `devtools::install_github("https://github.com/jpmam1/easi", dependencies = TRUE)`, e.g.

```r
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/jpmam1/easi", dependencies = TRUE)
#> Downloading GitHub repo jpmam1/easi@HEAD
#> 
#> * checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T/RtmpIVvyAO/remotes920f6a08f9/jpmam1-easi-1c90fed/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
#> * preparing ‘easi’:
#> * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
#> * checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#> * checking for empty or unneeded directories
#> * building ‘easi_0.2.tar.gz’
library(easi)

data(hixdata)

#******* Budget shares Matrix ************
shares_HIX=hixdata[,2:10]
#******* price Matrix (in logarithms) ****
log.price_HIX=hixdata[,11:19] 
#******* Demographic matrix **************
var.soc_HIX=hixdata[,21:25]
#******* logarithm of total expenditure **
#******* (here divised by a price index) *
log.exp_HIX=hixdata[,20]  

#******* Estimation... *******************
est <- easi(shares=shares_HIX,log.price=log.price_HIX,
            var.soc=var.soc_HIX,log.exp=log.exp_HIX)
#> 
#>  *** Please wait during the creation of final instruments... ***  
#> iteration =  1 
#> crit_test =  0.0132835 
#> iteration =  2 
#> crit_test =  0.0001305 
#> iteration =  3 
#> crit_test =  2e-06 
#> iteration =  4 
#> crit_test =  0 
#> 
#>  *** Creation of final instruments successfully completed... *** 
#> 
#>  *** Please wait during the estimation... *** 
#> iteration =  1 
#> crit_test =  0.000129 
#> iteration =  2 
#> crit_test =  0.0001305 
#> iteration =  3 
#> crit_test =  2e-06 
#> iteration =  4 
#> crit_test =  0 
#> 
#>  *** Estimation successfully completed ***

#******* Coefficients ********************
coef(est)
#>                    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> eq1_Constante  1.338565e-01 2.369823e-03  56.48376336 0.000000e+00
#> eq1_y^1       -6.191417e-02 4.024952e-03 -15.38258649 0.000000e+00
#> eq1_y^2        7.204632e-03 4.051263e-03   1.77836669 7.535151e-02
#> eq1_y^3       -5.431856e-03 4.554815e-03  -1.19255232 2.330521e-01
#> eq1_z1         1.271748e-03 8.724567e-05  14.57663475 0.000000e+00
#> eq1_z2        -1.132559e-02 1.965138e-03  -5.76325256 8.313371e-09
#> eq1_z3         1.792113e-02 2.234399e-03   8.02056136 1.110223e-15
#> eq1_z4        -6.937697e-05 3.847325e-04  -0.18032519 8.568982e-01
#> eq1_z5         1.138257e-02 2.681374e-03   4.24504945 2.190544e-05
#> eq1_ps1        1.589244e-03 2.153198e-02   0.07380854 9.411631e-01
#> eq1_ps2        1.999501e-02 1.821433e-02   1.09776281 2.723149e-01
#> eq1_ps3        1.204415e-02 1.194709e-02   1.00812378 3.134013e-01
#> eq1_ps4       -2.036881e-02 1.314895e-02  -1.54908326 1.213699e-01
#> eq1_ps5        6.430660e-02 1.789467e-02   3.59361758 3.265234e-04
#> eq1_ps6        2.736144e-03 1.342038e-02   0.20387973 8.384486e-01
#> eq1_ps7       -2.617399e-02 1.049025e-02  -2.49507691 1.259712e-02
#> eq1_ps8       -4.267075e-02 1.706035e-02  -2.50116548 1.238263e-02
#> eq2_Constante  1.007420e-01 2.336590e-03  43.11496556 0.000000e+00
#> eq2_y^1        3.902061e-02 3.836550e-03  10.17075381 0.000000e+00
#> eq2_y^2       -7.944056e-03 3.861890e-03  -2.05703858 3.968921e-02
#> eq2_y^3       -1.024568e-02 4.341767e-03  -2.35979428 1.829001e-02
#> eq2_z1        -4.310734e-04 8.314643e-05  -5.18450900 2.176728e-07
#> eq2_z2        -3.307872e-02 1.872796e-03 -17.66274360 0.000000e+00
#> eq2_z3         9.510982e-03 2.133540e-03   4.45784203 8.302140e-06
#> eq2_z4        -2.282785e-03 4.791944e-04  -4.76379778 1.906713e-06
#> eq2_z5        -1.336479e-02 2.558504e-03  -5.22367336 1.763154e-07
#> eq2_ps1        1.999501e-02 1.821433e-02   1.09776281 2.723149e-01
#> eq2_ps2        3.768766e-02 2.352883e-02   1.60176508 1.092157e-01
#> eq2_ps3       -7.950078e-03 1.317920e-02  -0.60322912 5.463598e-01
#> eq2_ps4        3.483069e-02 1.225491e-02   2.84218238 4.482930e-03
#> eq2_ps5       -6.409116e-02 2.007544e-02  -3.19251592 1.411520e-03
#> eq2_ps6       -6.061289e-02 1.550821e-02  -3.90843934 9.305247e-05
#> eq2_ps7       -3.616433e-03 1.076989e-02  -0.33579105 7.370303e-01
#> eq2_ps8        2.174694e-02 1.949804e-02   1.11533982 2.647118e-01
#> ...

# Summary
summary(est)
#> 
#> systemfit results 
#> method: 3SLS 
#> 
#>            N    DF     SSR detRCov   OLS-R2 McElroy-R2
#> system 38776 38668 158.669       0 0.280103   0.242627
#> 
#>       N   DF      SSR      MSE     RMSE       R2   Adj R2
#> s1 4847 4830 21.64543 0.004481 0.066944 0.309899 0.307613
#> s2 4847 4830 19.65986 0.004070 0.063799 0.168230 0.165474
#> s3 4847 4830 51.76049 0.010716 0.103520 0.310185 0.307900
#> s4 4847 4830  7.97288 0.001651 0.040629 0.110327 0.107380
#> s5 4847 4830 11.03250 0.002284 0.047793 0.123788 0.120886
#> s6 4847 4830 11.22150 0.002323 0.048201 0.268442 0.266019
#> s7 4847 4830 16.20021 0.003354 0.057914 0.455128 0.453323
#> s8 4847 4830 19.17577 0.003970 0.063009 0.192375 0.189700
#> 
#> The covariance matrix of the residuals used for estimation
#>              eq1          eq2         eq3          eq4          eq5
#> eq1  4.47448e-03 -1.09828e-03 -0.00173277 -3.30061e-05 -2.67632e-04
#> eq2 -1.09828e-03  4.06524e-03 -0.00172840 -2.51369e-04 -4.33163e-04
#> eq3 -1.73277e-03 -1.72840e-03  0.01070944 -1.08355e-03 -1.10554e-03
#> eq4 -3.30061e-05 -2.51369e-04 -0.00108355  1.65633e-03 -3.00605e-05
#> eq5 -2.67632e-04 -4.33163e-04 -0.00110554 -3.00605e-05  2.28601e-03
#> eq6 -3.28393e-04 -1.06748e-05 -0.00142407 -1.18782e-04 -6.13193e-06
#> eq7 -3.86588e-04 -1.76507e-04 -0.00148981 -2.79601e-05 -3.26869e-04
#> eq8 -5.46867e-04 -3.79785e-04 -0.00173404 -1.71792e-04 -1.12276e-04
#>              eq6          eq7          eq8
#> eq1 -3.28393e-04 -3.86588e-04 -0.000546867
#> eq2 -1.06748e-05 -1.76507e-04 -0.000379785
#> eq3 -1.42407e-03 -1.48981e-03 -0.001734042
#> eq4 -1.18782e-04 -2.79601e-05 -0.000171792
#> eq5 -6.13193e-06 -3.26869e-04 -0.000112276
#> eq6  2.32137e-03 -2.81616e-04 -0.000366797
#> eq7 -2.81616e-04  3.35286e-03 -0.000588504
#> eq8 -3.66797e-04 -5.88504e-04  0.003967409
#> 
#> The covariance matrix of the residuals
#>              eq1          eq2         eq3          eq4          eq5
#> eq1  0.004481456 -1.10511e-03 -0.00173530 -3.39720e-05 -2.68323e-04
#> eq2 -0.001105107  4.07036e-03 -0.00172900 -2.50759e-04 -4.37042e-04
#> eq3 -0.001735298 -1.72900e-03  0.01071646 -1.08676e-03 -1.09946e-03
#> eq4 -0.000033972 -2.50759e-04 -0.00108676  1.65070e-03 -3.02961e-05
#> eq5 -0.000268323 -4.37042e-04 -0.00109946 -3.02961e-05  2.28416e-03
#> eq6 -0.000328667 -5.49536e-06 -0.00143105 -1.14912e-04 -5.66993e-06
#> eq7 -0.000388075 -1.77368e-04 -0.00149217 -2.97562e-05 -3.25903e-04
#> eq8 -0.000545727 -3.78073e-04 -0.00173896 -1.71989e-04 -1.10871e-04
#>              eq6          eq7          eq8
#> eq1 -3.28667e-04 -3.88075e-04 -0.000545727
#> eq2 -5.49536e-06 -1.77368e-04 -0.000378073
#> eq3 -1.43105e-03 -1.49217e-03 -0.001738959
#> eq4 -1.14912e-04 -2.97562e-05 -0.000171989
#> eq5 -5.66993e-06 -3.25903e-04 -0.000110871
#> eq6  2.32329e-03 -2.84649e-04 -0.000363633
#> eq7 -2.84649e-04  3.35408e-03 -0.000591536
#> eq8 -3.63633e-04 -5.91536e-04  0.003970139
#> 
#> The correlations of the residuals
#>            eq1         eq2       eq3        eq4         eq5         eq6
#> eq1  1.0000000 -0.25874870 -0.250403 -0.0124904 -0.08386578 -0.10185775
#> eq2 -0.2587487  1.00000000 -0.261789 -0.0967399 -0.14333193 -0.00178701
#> eq3 -0.2504027 -0.26178923  1.000000 -0.2583893 -0.22222295 -0.28679858
#> eq4 -0.0124904 -0.09673985 -0.258389  1.0000000 -0.01560230 -0.05867860
#> eq5 -0.0838658 -0.14333193 -0.222223 -0.0156023  1.00000000 -0.00246129
#> eq6 -0.1018577 -0.00178701 -0.286799 -0.0586786 -0.00246129  1.00000000
#> eq7 -0.1000967 -0.04800352 -0.248889 -0.0126461 -0.11774395 -0.10196952
#> eq8 -0.1293787 -0.09404945 -0.266600 -0.0671837 -0.03681726 -0.11973159
#>            eq7        eq8
#> eq1 -0.1000967 -0.1293787
#> eq2 -0.0480035 -0.0940494
#> eq3 -0.2488887 -0.2666005
#> eq4 -0.0126461 -0.0671837
#> eq5 -0.1177440 -0.0368173
#> eq6 -0.1019695 -0.1197316
#> eq7  1.0000000 -0.1621032
#> eq8 -0.1621032  1.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's1' (equation 1)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe638b791c8>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  1.33857e-01  2.36982e-03  56.48376 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1       -6.19142e-02  4.02495e-03 -15.38259 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^2        7.20463e-03  4.05126e-03   1.77837 0.07535151 .  
#> y^3       -5.43186e-03  4.55482e-03  -1.19255 0.23305207    
#> z1         1.27175e-03  8.72457e-05  14.57663 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z2        -1.13256e-02  1.96514e-03  -5.76325 8.3134e-09 ***
#> z3         1.79211e-02  2.23440e-03   8.02056 1.1102e-15 ***
#> z4        -6.93770e-05  3.84732e-04  -0.18033 0.85689823    
#> z5         1.13826e-02  2.68137e-03   4.24505 2.1905e-05 ***
#> ps1        1.58924e-03  2.15320e-02   0.07381 0.94116312    
#> ps2        1.99950e-02  1.82143e-02   1.09776 0.27231491    
#> ps3        1.20441e-02  1.19471e-02   1.00812 0.31340135    
#> ps4       -2.03688e-02  1.31489e-02  -1.54908 0.12136989    
#> ps5        6.43066e-02  1.78947e-02   3.59362 0.00032652 ***
#> ps6        2.73614e-03  1.34204e-02   0.20388 0.83844856    
#> ps7       -2.61740e-02  1.04903e-02  -2.49508 0.01259712 *  
#> ps8       -4.26708e-02  1.70603e-02  -2.50117 0.01238263 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.066944 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 21.645434 MSE: 0.004481 Root MSE: 0.066944 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.309899 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.307613 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's2' (equation 2)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe638ab1510>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  1.00742e-01  2.33659e-03  43.11497 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1        3.90206e-02  3.83655e-03  10.17075 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^2       -7.94406e-03  3.86189e-03  -2.05704  0.0396892 *  
#> y^3       -1.02457e-02  4.34177e-03  -2.35979  0.0182900 *  
#> z1        -4.31073e-04  8.31464e-05  -5.18451 2.1767e-07 ***
#> z2        -3.30787e-02  1.87280e-03 -17.66274 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z3         9.51098e-03  2.13354e-03   4.45784 8.3021e-06 ***
#> z4        -2.28279e-03  4.79194e-04  -4.76380 1.9067e-06 ***
#> z5        -1.33648e-02  2.55850e-03  -5.22367 1.7632e-07 ***
#> ps1        1.99950e-02  1.82143e-02   1.09776  0.2723149    
#> ps2        3.76877e-02  2.35288e-02   1.60177  0.1092157    
#> ps3       -7.95008e-03  1.31792e-02  -0.60323  0.5463598    
#> ps4        3.48307e-02  1.22549e-02   2.84218  0.0044829 ** 
#> ps5       -6.40912e-02  2.00754e-02  -3.19252  0.0014115 ** 
#> ps6       -6.06129e-02  1.55082e-02  -3.90844 9.3052e-05 ***
#> ps7       -3.61643e-03  1.07699e-02  -0.33579  0.7370303    
#> ps8        2.17469e-02  1.94980e-02   1.11534  0.2647118    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.063799 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 19.659859 MSE: 0.00407 Root MSE: 0.063799 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.16823 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.165474 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's3' (equation 3)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe638a587f0>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  0.341632535  0.003138294 108.85932 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1       -0.141730466  0.006225420 -22.76641 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^2       -0.044153992  0.006267277  -7.04516 1.8834e-12 ***
#> y^3        0.057029303  0.007045841   8.09404 4.4409e-16 ***
#> z1         0.000836942  0.000134738   6.21161 5.2978e-10 ***
#> z2         0.011815851  0.003038546   3.88865 0.00010097 ***
#> z3         0.034858317  0.003452690  10.09599 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z4         0.003609541  0.000378017   9.54863 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z5         0.013475472  0.004145172   3.25088 0.00115145 ** 
#> ps1        0.012044145  0.011947089   1.00812 0.31340135    
#> ps2       -0.007950078  0.013179200  -0.60323 0.54635982    
#> ps3        0.068069679  0.016510980   4.12269 3.7525e-05 ***
#> ps4       -0.012995886  0.008152114  -1.59417 0.11090531    
#> ps5        0.023882356  0.013056226   1.82919 0.06737841 .  
#> ps6       -0.024377790  0.009860607  -2.47224 0.01343120 *  
#> ps7       -0.009473078  0.010789996  -0.87795 0.37997626    
#> ps8       -0.024124565  0.013387121  -1.80207 0.07154175 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.10352 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 51.760485 MSE: 0.010716 Root MSE: 0.10352 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.310185 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.3079 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's4' (equation 4)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe6389fe748>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  4.84964e-02  1.50619e-03 32.19806 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1        7.27329e-03  2.44900e-03  2.96991 0.00298074 ** 
#> y^2        1.08792e-02  2.46514e-03  4.41322 1.0212e-05 ***
#> y^3       -8.20989e-03  2.77139e-03 -2.96237 0.00305468 ** 
#> z1        -1.62026e-04  5.31058e-05 -3.05099 0.00228241 ** 
#> z2         1.77838e-02  1.19562e-03 14.87405 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z3         9.06894e-03  1.36008e-03  6.66796 2.6286e-11 ***
#> z4         5.12632e-04  2.85747e-04  1.79401 0.07281928 .  
#> z5         5.72461e-03  1.63275e-03  3.50611 0.00045522 ***
#> ps1       -2.03688e-02  1.31489e-02 -1.54908 0.12136989    
#> ps2        3.48307e-02  1.22549e-02  2.84218 0.00448293 ** 
#> ps3       -1.29959e-02  8.15211e-03 -1.59417 0.11090531    
#> ps4        4.33578e-02  1.21347e-02  3.57306 0.00035326 ***
#> ps5       -2.76387e-02  1.38733e-02 -1.99222 0.04635406 *  
#> ps6       -9.33810e-03  1.05280e-02 -0.88698 0.37509727    
#> ps7       -2.86846e-02  7.62226e-03 -3.76326 0.00016796 ***
#> ps8        3.11561e-02  1.28851e-02  2.41798 0.01561134 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.040629 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 7.972878 MSE: 0.001651 Root MSE: 0.040629 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.110327 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.10738 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's5' (equation 5)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe6389a95f0>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  3.28683e-02  1.91029e-03 17.20593 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1        4.47148e-02  2.87743e-03 15.53986 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^2        1.60626e-02  2.89648e-03  5.54554 2.9495e-08 ***
#> y^3       -5.28537e-03  3.25613e-03 -1.62321 0.10455363    
#> z1        -9.75294e-05  6.23902e-05 -1.56322 0.11800985    
#> z2         1.00156e-02  1.40536e-03  7.12672 1.0458e-12 ***
#> z3         7.99729e-03  1.59900e-03  5.00143 5.7156e-07 ***
#> z4         1.83941e-04  6.53334e-04  0.28154 0.77829675    
#> z5         1.50144e-03  1.91974e-03  0.78211 0.43415734    
#> ps1        6.43066e-02  1.78947e-02  3.59362 0.00032652 ***
#> ps2       -6.40912e-02  2.00754e-02 -3.19252 0.00141152 ** 
#> ps3        2.38824e-02  1.30562e-02  1.82919 0.06737841 .  
#> ps4       -2.76387e-02  1.38733e-02 -1.99222 0.04635406 *  
#> ps5       -1.35335e-02  3.82061e-02 -0.35422 0.72317415    
#> ps6        2.73453e-02  1.72358e-02  1.58654 0.11262429    
#> ps7       -1.29348e-02  9.80867e-03 -1.31872 0.18727197    
#> ps8       -1.21020e-02  3.03183e-02 -0.39916 0.68977392    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.047793 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 11.032503 MSE: 0.002284 Root MSE: 0.047793 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.123788 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.120886 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's6' (equation 6)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe638950a90>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  6.80334e-02  1.79089e-03 37.98871 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1        5.36278e-02  2.89953e-03 18.49537 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^2        2.08672e-02  2.91840e-03  7.15022 8.8174e-13 ***
#> y^3       -5.14651e-03  3.28118e-03 -1.56850 0.11677353    
#> z1        -3.88915e-04  6.28457e-05 -6.18842 6.1380e-10 ***
#> z2         2.64340e-02  1.41533e-03 18.67694 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z3         1.12155e-02  1.61008e-03  6.96578 3.3182e-12 ***
#> z4        -9.50025e-04  3.64889e-04 -2.60360 0.00922851 ** 
#> z5        -8.57483e-03  1.93257e-03 -4.43702 9.1466e-06 ***
#> ps1        2.73614e-03  1.34204e-02  0.20388 0.83844856    
#> ps2       -6.06129e-02  1.55082e-02 -3.90844 9.3052e-05 ***
#> ps3       -2.43778e-02  9.86061e-03 -2.47224 0.01343120 *  
#> ps4       -9.33810e-03  1.05280e-02 -0.88698 0.37509727    
#> ps5        2.73453e-02  1.72358e-02  1.58654 0.11262429    
#> ps6        6.03096e-02  1.73455e-02  3.47695 0.00050771 ***
#> ps7        3.42362e-02  8.49490e-03  4.03020 5.5835e-05 ***
#> ps8        2.31777e-02  1.72462e-02  1.34393 0.17897735    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.048201 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 11.221504 MSE: 0.002323 Root MSE: 0.048201 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.268442 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.266019 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's7' (equation 7)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe6388f7d60>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  1.70753e-01  2.02047e-03  84.51116 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1       -1.48181e-02  3.48399e-03  -4.25320 2.1123e-05 ***
#> y^2       -2.28009e-02  3.50664e-03  -6.50221 8.0113e-11 ***
#> y^3       -2.47867e-03  3.94290e-03  -0.62864 0.52958738    
#> z1        -1.73485e-04  7.54648e-05  -2.29888 0.02151685 *  
#> z2        -1.28792e-02  1.70036e-03  -7.57438 3.6859e-14 ***
#> z3        -1.04241e-01  1.93289e-03 -53.92997 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z4        -7.13305e-04  2.98228e-04  -2.39181 0.01677046 *  
#> z5        -8.31338e-03  2.31990e-03  -3.58350 0.00033944 ***
#> ps1       -2.61740e-02  1.04903e-02  -2.49508 0.01259712 *  
#> ps2       -3.61643e-03  1.07699e-02  -0.33579 0.73703026    
#> ps3       -9.47308e-03  1.07900e-02  -0.87795 0.37997626    
#> ps4       -2.86846e-02  7.62226e-03  -3.76326 0.00016796 ***
#> ps5       -1.29348e-02  9.80867e-03  -1.31872 0.18727197    
#> ps6        3.42362e-02  8.49490e-03   4.03020 5.5835e-05 ***
#> ps7        4.26305e-02  1.15967e-02   3.67608 0.00023716 ***
#> ps8       -4.02475e-03  1.03864e-02  -0.38750 0.69838808    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.057914 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 16.200205 MSE: 0.003354 Root MSE: 0.057914 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.455128 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.453323 
#> 
#> 
#> 3SLS estimates for 's8' (equation 8)
#> Model Formula: ~+Constante + y^1 + y^2 + y^3 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + 
#>     ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8
#> <environment: 0x7fe63889fbd8>
#> Instruments: [1] "~ + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + ps1 + ps2 + ps3 + ps4 + ps5 + ps6 + ps7 + ps8 + inst_y^1 + inst_y^2 + inst_y^3"
#> 
#>               Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)    
#> Constante  8.30862e-02  2.24518e-03  37.00645 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^1        6.77452e-02  3.79020e-03  17.87379 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> y^2        2.06887e-02  3.81507e-03   5.42288 5.8997e-08 ***
#> y^3       -1.35795e-02  4.28911e-03  -3.16605  0.0015465 ** 
#> z1        -7.79162e-04  8.21321e-05  -9.48669 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z2        -2.54823e-02  1.85051e-03 -13.77045 < 2.22e-16 ***
#> z3         1.02558e-02  2.10396e-03   4.87451 1.0951e-06 ***
#> z4         3.40386e-04  5.87519e-04   0.57936  0.5623482    
#> z5        -7.86386e-04  2.52459e-03  -0.31149  0.7554293    
#> ps1       -4.26708e-02  1.70603e-02  -2.50117  0.0123826 *  
#> ps2        2.17469e-02  1.94980e-02   1.11534  0.2647118    
#> ps3       -2.41246e-02  1.33871e-02  -1.80207  0.0715418 .  
#> ps4        3.11561e-02  1.28851e-02   2.41798  0.0156113 *  
#> ps5       -1.21020e-02  3.03183e-02  -0.39916  0.6897739    
#> ps6        2.31777e-02  1.72462e-02   1.34393  0.1789773    
#> ps7       -4.02475e-03  1.03864e-02  -0.38750  0.6983881    
#> ps8       -1.02249e-02  2.98625e-02  -0.34240  0.7320531    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.063009 on 4830 degrees of freedom
#> Number of observations: 4847 Degrees of Freedom: 4830 
#> SSR: 19.175769 MSE: 0.00397 Root MSE: 0.063009 
#> Multiple R-Squared: 0.192375 Adjusted R-Squared: 0.1897

# fitted values
head(predict(est))
#>             s1          s2        s3         s4         s5         s6
#> [1,] 0.3148521 0.007088799 0.2718483 0.10431671 0.04797565 0.12398362
#> [2,] 0.2815752 0.007296639 0.3765217 0.07960349 0.03833235 0.11151020
#> [3,] 0.2159977 0.068854341 0.3748992 0.04737345 0.03658791 0.09920668
#> [4,] 0.2333557 0.069060035 0.3759948 0.04441345 0.02861974 0.09857289
#> [5,] 0.1253354 0.103084623 0.2460621 0.03725748 0.04965151 0.12915065
#> [6,] 0.2247643 0.075434197 0.3746137 0.03903780 0.03360408 0.10165050
#>              s7         s8
#> [1,] 0.03439408 0.04200202
#> [2,] 0.04535731 0.01645048
#> [3,] 0.07163017 0.06119997
#> [4,] 0.07645149 0.04879235
#> [5,] 0.18377317 0.09936264
#> [6,] 0.07717741 0.04963816

# Residuals 
head(residuals(est))
#>            s1           s2          s3           s4          s5            s6
#> 1  0.19184705 -0.007088799  0.09355974 -0.094572495  0.01048964 -0.0764805708
#> 2 -0.02243903 -0.007296639  0.22148493 -0.007344349 -0.03833235 -0.0699819603
#> 3  0.23676673 -0.036203058 -0.08060230 -0.031265482 -0.03658791 -0.0099598331
#> 4  0.02755754 -0.058021400 -0.14117293 -0.014308084 -0.01557408  0.1026313179
#> 5 -0.11269960  0.092265383  0.02687199  0.013538576 -0.02791788  0.0275337059
#> 6  0.00672091 -0.014730029 -0.08201964 -0.007066936 -0.03319938 -0.0008815854
#>             s7            s8
#> 1 -0.030740001 -0.0383479352
#> 2 -0.045357306 -0.0006697501
#> 3  0.016745977 -0.0524929638
#> 4 -0.040826807  0.1499030874
#> 5  0.055044122 -0.0708056495
#> 6  0.008617811  0.1219522859

# Covariance Matrix
dim(vcov(est))
#> [1] 136 136
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Update 05-JUN-2023

Fixed several bugs in the `engel()` function @Prasanna S; if you reinstall the package, it should now work as expected:

```r
# reinstall the updated package
remotes::install_github("jpmam1/easi", force = TRUE)
#> Downloading GitHub repo jpmam1/easi@HEAD
#> 
#> ── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> * checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T/Rtmp5uN9An/remotes5734e908d92/jpmam1-easi-26fc918/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
#> * preparing ‘easi’:
#> * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
#> * checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#> * checking for empty or unneeded directories
#> * building ‘easi_0.2.tar.gz’
library(easi)

easi::hixdemo()
#> 
#>  *** Please wait during the creation of final instruments... ***  
#> iteration =  1 
#> crit_test =  0.0132835 
#> iteration =  2 
#> crit_test =  0.0001305 
#> iteration =  3 
#> crit_test =  2e-06 
#> iteration =  4 
#> crit_test =  0 
#> 
#>  *** Creation of final instruments successfully completed... *** 
#> 
#>  *** Please wait during the estimation... *** 
#> iteration =  1 
#> crit_test =  0.000129 
#> iteration =  2 
#> crit_test =  0.0001305 
#> iteration =  3 
#> crit_test =  2e-06 
#> iteration =  4 
#> crit_test =  0 
#> 
#>  *** Estimation successfully completed ***
#> 
#> systemfit results 
#> method:  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> NULL

shares_HIX=hixdata[,2:10]
log.price_HIX=hixdata[,11:19] 
var.soc_HIX=hixdata[,21:25]
log.exp_HIX=hixdata[,20]  

est <- easi(shares=shares_HIX,log.price=log.price_HIX,
            var.soc=var.soc_HIX,log.exp=log.exp_HIX)
#> 
#>  *** Please wait during the creation of final instruments... ***  
#> iteration =  1 
#> crit_test =  0.0132835 
#> iteration =  2 
#> crit_test =  0.0001305 
#> iteration =  3 
#> crit_test =  2e-06 
#> iteration =  4 
#> crit_test =  0 
#> 
#>  *** Creation of final instruments successfully completed... *** 
#> 
#>  *** Please wait during the estimation... *** 
#> iteration =  1 
#> crit_test =  0.000129 
#> iteration =  2 
#> crit_test =  0.0001305 
#> iteration =  3 
#> crit_test =  2e-06 
#> iteration =  4 
#> crit_test =  0 
#> 
#>  *** Estimation successfully completed ***

engel(object = est, file = "graph_engels_curves", sd = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image: 1.png]

[image: 2.png]

[image: 3.png]

[image: 4.png]

[image: 5.png]

[image: 6.png]

[image: 7.png]

[image: 8.png]

[image: 9.png]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it later today and get back to you shortly!!!

Comment: @jared_mamrot, The ```easi``` function of the package runs well. I got the outputs of the ```elastic``` function which takes in an object of type ```easi``` as input. However, I am unable to get outputs from  the function ```engel```. I ran this code:
```eng1 <- engel(est,file="graph_engels_curves",sd=FALSE)``` given in the package vignette, but it returned this error:
Error in if (write.file) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. Could you help me find solution to this error?

Comment: I've updated the package @PrasannaS; the `engel()` function had a number of bugs/issues, but it should now work as expected. If you have any other issues, please feel free to leave further comments :)